# Injecting a custom property from application.properties in quarkus

Tags: java, properties, quarkus

Following the guide [here](https://quarkus.io/guides/config) I am trying to inject my own custom property that I defined in application.properties.
The prop is defined as `sendgrid.apikey=key` and then my class is;

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class EmailConfig {

    @Inject
    @ConfigProperty(name = "sendgrid.apikey")
    String API_KEY;

    private SendGrid sendGrid;
    private Request request;

    public EmailConfig() {
        sendGrid = new SendGrid(API_KEY);
        request = new Request();
    }
```

When I hit the first line in the constructor, I expect `API_KEY` to be the value in the application.properties file, but it is `null`. I have no idea why! I tried this with and without the `@Inject` annotation btw.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your expectation is wrong. There are tricks for creating an instance of a class without calling a constructor, but they are generally not exactly reliable, so what Quarkus does is what you would do by hand: to create an instance, it calls the constructor. Only after an instance exists can fields be injected.

What you can do is inject objects into the constructor as its parameters:

```java
@ApplicationScoped
public class EmailConfig {

    private SendGrid sendGrid;
    private Request request;

    @Inject
    public EmailConfig(@ConfigProperty(name = "sendgrid.apikey") String API_KEY) {
        sendGrid = new SendGrid(API_KEY);
        request = new Request();
    }
```

Comment: Can you not inject over the instance variable? i.e. have the Inject and ConfigProperty annotations over the instance variable?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question.

Comment: So you are doing a constructor injection. Can you just do it like 
@Inject 
@ConfigProperty(name = "sendgrid.apikey") 
private String key

Comment: ^^^ Can't put that on newlines but that is meant to indicate having the annotations on the instance variable

Comment: Of course you can do that, but as I explained in this answer, those fields will be injected _after_ the constructor finishes. Another alternative is to use field injection and instead of a constructor, use a `@PostConstruct` method.